# Laptop HDD fail, Shows partition but can not copy data, testdisk MBR code fail

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, partition-recovery, hard-drive-failure, testdisk

I use 2TB HDD in my laptop with 250 GB partition for windows 10 and rest for data storage. I switched my laptop so moved the HDD from old to new laptop and started the system. Windows logo came up but within a minute laptop crashed and then after nothing worked. I took out the HDD and plugged externally to another windows 10 system where it shows both the partition mounted with their respective sizes. When I open the drive it shows folders as well but when I open or copy any of the folder it gives error "The device is not ready".

I tried using minitool and recuva data recovery but it failed to detect anything.

Then I plugged the HDD externally to Ubuntu system. Gparted shows 3 partitions, 1) ntfs system reserved 549 MiB, 2) ntfs Windows 250 GiB, 3) ntfs 1.57 TiB. But the direct data copy or testdisk fails.

I used testdisk to analyse lost partitions but nothing is reported, even in deep search. I then used the MBR code but even that failed.

I also used gddrescue to copy image the entire disk which ran for ~ 24 hours and made the image file of 800 GB. Following is the output of log:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue /dev/sdb /media/v/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/copy.img /media/v/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/status.log
# Start time:   2018-11-29 12:16:31
# Current time: 2018-11-30 11:33:28
# Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status
0xC21A8B0000     ?
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0xBF655E0000  +
0xBF655E0000  0x00010000  *
0xBF655F0000  0x00010000  ?
0xBF65600000  0x7F078000  +
0xBFE4678000  0x00008000  *
0xBFE4680000  0x00010000  ?
0xBFE4690000  0xA9DC0000  +
0xC08E450000  0x00010000  *
0xC08E460000  0x00010000  ?
0xC08E470000  0xDDADC000  +
0xC16BF4C000  0x00004000  *
0xC16BF50000  0x00010000  ?
0xC16BF60000  0xAE950000  +
0xC21A8B0000  0x2E166F25E00  ?
```

I have important data in Data partition so I do not want to take risky steps. So I am now posting this question for help.

**Update 20181201**
I ran ddrescue and following is the current status.
[ddrescue status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4g4f.png)

Any idea why the recent blocks are full of errors? I see a trend that somewhere in middle many red block are coming? Could it be that the rest of the blocks will follow the same trend henceforth? How do I see which files have been rescued in the green area?

Kindly suggest how to rescue the data on the disk.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You really don't want to connect an internal drive to USB as it can mess up block sizes etc. Try plugging it in via SATA or esata. (Gnu) ddrescue can certainly set to stop recovery and restart. I'd be inclined to fo this, adding the -r switch so it starts recovering from the end - which may recover more data quickly or help you scope the problem.

Answer (score 0):

...here's my first try to help someone. I hope, I can..:-)

First of all I think it would be interesting to know if a manufacturers diagnostic tool says that the hdd is okay.

If the tool does not find any Errors on the Hardware, I can recommend EaseUs. I tried the Software some months ago on a broken USB stick and was able to recover all data.

Here's the link to the Trial Version:
https://www.easeus.com/ppc/data-recovery-bing.html?msclkid=4fc2675dbdcb1407fd7f3b5cbac0b6ff&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=drw-data%20type-search-eu&utm_term=data%20recovery&utm_content=data

In my case the Software was able to recover an USB stick which was completely unreadable, even plugged to a Debian vm. The Software is selfexplaining that is why I do not write any instructions. The Trial will find all lost files, but recovery of all files will only be possible by buying the program.

I recommend this software because of my good experiences.

Comment: Hi google.com, thank you for the response. I tried connected the disk to another system to check with seatools. Unfortunately tool does not even detect the drive. I have already tried using easeus but it also fails to detect the HDD.